# Body drawing and collision zone are shifted

Tags: lua, box2d, sdl-2, love2d

I'm starting to use love2d's physics module to make a game.

I tried making a (horizontal) wall object for the player to walk on, but there's a problem:
the player can pass through part of where the wall drawing is (this happens on the right) and it can walk over what looks like "air" to the left of the wall.

it seems that the collision zone and the drawing do not overlap perfectly.

this is how I'm building the wall (in `Wall` class):

```
 function Wall:new(x, y, w, h, world)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.w = w
    self.h = h

    self.body = love.physics.newBody(world, self.x, self.y, "kinematic")
    self.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(self.w, self.h)
    self.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(self.body, self.shape, 100)
end
```

and I'm calling the constructor with these variables (in `main.lua`)

```
objects.wall = Wall(40, height - 60, 200, 5, world)
```

this is how I'm drawing it (in `Wall` class)

```
love.graphics.rectangle("fill", self.body:getX(), self.body:getY(), self.w, self.h)
```

I'm using `rxi/classic` to make classes.

The wall is drawn, it just interacts weirdly with the player.

screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6hEf.jpg

Comment: Mind posting a screenshot?

Comment: @user6245072 done that

Comment: Could it be a problem with the meter you used?

Comment: Or maybe a problem with the player more than the wall

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `newRectangleShape` requires the x and y coordinates for the centre of the rectangle, and my draw function was wrong because i was considering x and y to be the coordinates of the top-left corner.